# Subsetting results from sapply

Tags: r, sapply

After I use sapply, I get a list, and I would like to access individual elements of those lists. So far, I have:

```
large.list <- sapply(1:length(visit_num), function(x)  
    seq(enter.shift.want[x], to= exit.prime[x], by= 'hour'))
```

where enter.shift.want and exit.prime are vectors of dates.

```
head(large.list, 2)
[[1]]
 [1] "1982-05-17 13:00:00 PDT" "1982-05-17 14:00:00 PDT" "1982-05-17 15:00:00 PDT"
 [4] "1982-05-17 16:00:00 PDT" "1982-05-17 17:00:00 PDT" "1982-05-17 18:00:00 PDT"
 [7] "1982-05-17 19:00:00 PDT" "1982-05-17 20:00:00 PDT" "1982-05-17 21:00:00 PDT"
[10] "1982-05-17 22:00:00 PDT"

[[2]]
 [1] "1982-07-14 13:00:00 PDT" "1982-07-14 14:00:00 PDT" "1982-07-14 15:00:00 PDT"
 [4] "1982-07-14 16:00:00 PDT" "1982-07-14 17:00:00 PDT" "1982-07-14 18:00:00 PDT"
 [7] "1982-07-14 19:00:00 PDT" "1982-07-14 20:00:00 PDT" "1982-07-14 21:00:00 PDT"
[10] "1982-07-14 22:00:00 PDT"
```

I would like to have large.list[1] as a vector of dates/time.
Then I would like to do

```
large.list[1]<=enter.shift.want[1]
```

and get a vector of true and false results. Then I would want generalize and do 
 `large.list[n]<= enter.shift.want[n]` for each `n` in `(1:length(visit_num))` , and add up the true/falses.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be using `[[` indexing instead of `[` on the list elements if you want the vector itself and not a list. We're also going to need to see a sample of the other data sets

Comment: What is your desired result? You could create a data.frame out of this list by doing something like `do.call(cbind, large.list)`

Answer (score 0):

If `enter.shift.want` is a `list` or a `vector` with same number of elements as `large.list`, here is one way to apply it to the whole `list`.

```
 res <- Map(`<=`, large.list, enter.shift.want)
 res1 <- Map(`<=`, large.list, enter.shift.want1)
```

To get the total number of `TRUE` per list element

```
 colSums(do.call(cbind, res))
 #[1] 3 3
```

Or

```
 sapply(res, sum)
 #[1] 3 3

 sapply(res1,sum)
 #[1] 3 7
```

#### data

```
 large.list <- list(structure(c(390488400, 390492000, 390495600, 390499200, 
 390502800, 390506400, 390510000, 390513600, 390517200, 390520800
 ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "PDT"), structure(c(395499600, 
 395503200, 395506800, 395510400, 395514000, 395517600, 395521200, 
 395524800, 395528400, 395532000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
 ), tzone = "PDT"))


 v1 <- c('1982-05-17 00:00:00', '1982-07-14 00:00:00')
 enter.shift.want <- lapply(v1, function(x) seq(as.POSIXct(x, tz='PDT'),
          length.out=10, by='3 hour'))

 enter.shift.want1 <- as.POSIXct(c('1982-05-17 15:00:00', 
                     '1982-07-14 19:00:00'), tz='PDT')
```